# Base.lproj/MainMenu.xib is not available when compiling for targets before Mac OS X 10.8

Tags: xcode, cocoa, warnings, xcode5

I'm very new to Cocoa development.
I've just created Cocoa project in **Xcode 5**. I changed **Deployment Target** from 10.8 to 10.6. Now I get this warning:

> path-to-my-project/Base.lproj/MainMenu.xib is not available when
>   compiling for targets before Mac OS X 10.8

Is it normal behavior? What should I do?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Your project is using base internationalization, which makes translating your app to other spoken languages easier. Base internationalization is supported on Mac OS X 10.8 and later, which is why you are getting the warning when you changed the deployment target to 10.6.

There are two ways to get rid of the warning. First, you can set the deployment target to 10.8. Second, you can turn off base internationalization. Select your project from the project navigator to open the project editor. Select your project from the left side of the project editor. Deselect the Use Base Internationalization checkbox.

[image]

Comment: I found you have to do *both* of these for 10.7.

Answer (score 2):

For those who find that turning off base localization deletes the .xib in a new project, another option is to select MainMenu.xib, choose the ‘File Inspector’ on the right (looks like a 'new file' icon).  Go down to Localization and uncheck Base.

Answer (score 0):

There is another way:

- Remove references from all files in Base.lproj from the project
- Move files from Base.lproj to ..
- Add those files again in the project.