# Edit GUI without using base internationalization

Tags: xcode, interface-builder

I set my Xcode 5 project to use a build target of OSX 10.6, unchecked "Use Autolayout" for MainMenu.xib and followed [this answer to turn off base internationalization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18917278/base-lproj-mainmenu-xib-is-not-available-when-compiling-for-targets-before-mac-o/18923803#18923803). This resulted in my MainMenu.xib file being removed from my project. When I build and run my project the window layout is how I left it, but going into finder, opening MainMenu.xib in Interface Builder and changing it's layout does not effect my project when I go to build and run it again.

How do I change the GUI for projects set to a build target of 10.6?

Comment: @matt I am new to Xcode, so I could be wrong, but using base internationalization results in a warning when building to platforms older than 10.8. I assume this might cause issues when running on older systems, or get the project rejected from the App Store?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can be added again to the project by:

1. Drag `MainMenu.xib` from Finder to the project files panel in Xcode.
2. A dialog will open, select *copy items (if needed)*, *created folder references*, and add to the project's target (not "test"), click *Finish* and it should work!

If a more complete answer is added, I will best answer it instead of my own.