# Deployment Target and Different OSXs

Tags: xcode, macos

here is my dev/project settings:
Deployment Target - 10.6
SDK: 10.9
Architecture: Universal 32/64.

Now when I archive and try to run it on ML 10.8 (other machine not my dev machine); It crashes and gives me "Classic environment is o longer supported" error.

I have not tested it yet on 10.6 though but what is the best way to keep my app running fine on all of them 10.6+ ?

Also I am using ASIHTTP and setting it to "-fno-objc-arc" in build-phases.

Please help.

I have set my project's Deployment Target to 10.6 to support older machines.

Comment: IIRC I've seen this error when the app's bundle structure was damaged. How dod you copy the app to the 10.8 computer, and are you sure it got there intact?

Answer (score 1):

The `Classic environment is no longer supported` shouldn't be occurring based on the information your provide, as that refers to code written for OS 9, not OS X. However, based off of my own experience ([this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21190308/xcode-5-cocoa-app-fails-to-load-nib-on-os-x-10-6)), besides setting the deployment target to 10.6, you must also turn off base internationalization and auto layout for your NIBs. Good luck!